# finding the length of the GCD of two strings

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, strings

Let's say you have two strings: `a` and `b` with GCD `c`. Why is it that `len(GCD) = gcd(len(a), len(b))`?

Comment: How do you define the GCD of two strings?

Comment: This is the updated post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748211/does-a-gcd-for-two-strings-exist-if-so-what-is-the-length/4748244#4748244